# wordpress site auto redirect to another site when I enable woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect

When I enable Woocommerce this message will show at the top of my website backend:
Your store does not appear to be using a secure connection. We highly recommend serving your entire website over an HTTPS connection to help keep customer data secure. Learn more here.

And when I open my site, it will be redirected to this address(market-online.ir is not my domain):
http://www.market-online.ir/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js?ver=2.70
I’ve installed a new WordPress in subdomain and then I’ve installed woocommerce and the problem appears again.
Please tell me how can I solve this problem.

Comment: you move site one domain to another domain?

Comment: No, I didn't move my site. I've created new wordpress site in subdomain.

Comment: ok please send main domain and subdomain name

Comment: please check WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL). in admin setting->general

Comment: i add some code please use  and check site . i hope solve your problem.